# When using strcpy() does the destination string need to be one element bigger than the source string?

Tags: c, strcpy

Consider this code snippet (simplified syntax for clarity).

```
void simple (char *bar) {
    char MyArray[12];
    strcpy(MyArray, bar);
}
```

My instructor says that ***MyArray*** can copy at most 12 elements from ***bar***, but from what I've read, MyArray can only store 11 characters because it needs room for the null character at the end. So if the received value of ***bar*** is 12 or greater, a buffer overflow would occur. My instructor says that this will only happen if the received value of ***bar*** 
is 13 or greater. Who's right? I'd appreciate if you could cite a credible source so I can convince him.

Comment: `man strncpy` is fully answering this question.

Comment: `man strcpy`. _The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest._

Comment: @Oka, your quote is incomplete and therefore wrong.

Comment: @Akhil Pothana  Are you speaking about strcpy or strncpy?

Comment: Nothing will overflow, but if `(len(src) >= siz)` the resulting string will not be null-terminated, which is just as bad, or maybe even worse.

Comment: The title says `strncpy` but the code uses `strcpy`. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I am referring to strcpy(), the strncpy() was a typo

Answer (score 5):

The definition `char MyArray[12]` creates an array of 12 `char`, which can be used to store a string.  Since strings in C are null terminated, one of those characters needs to be able to store the null byte at the end of the string.

So a variable of type `char [12]` can hold a string of at most 11 characters.  Attempting to copy a string of length 12 or longer using `strcpy` as in your example will overflow the bounds of the array.

If you were to use `strncpy` as follows:

```
strncpy(MyArray, bar, 12);
```

This will not overflow the buffer, as it would copy at most 12 characters.  However, if 12 characters are copied, that means the string is not null terminated and is therefore not technically a string.  Then attempting to use any other string function on `MyArray` that expect a null terminated string would read off the end of the array.

Comment: The question is about `strncpy`. It copies upto `n` bytes and then does not add the terminating null character. An array of 12 chars can hold 12 chars. The null byte is a problem of the person calling strncpy.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  The title says `strncpy` but the example given uses `strcpy`.  I've updated to address both.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `strncpy` *does* copy the terminating null character, if it can, that is, if there's room.  (But the fact that `strncpy` might or might not copy the terminating null character makes it basically useless.)

Comment: @SteveSummit You *can* use it, but you need to be disciplined enough to manually add the null terminator after using it.

Comment: @dbush Thank you, this clarified it for me perfectly. My instructor is adamant that he is correct for some reason even though I've cited the C book Dennis Ritchie wrote himself. This is an intermediate information security class, so maybe he doesn't really know.

Answer (score 2):

The/a proper use of strncpy would be:

```
void simple(char *bar) {
    char MyArray[12];
    strncpy(MyArray, bar, sizeof(MyArray)-1);
    MyArray[sizeof(MyArray)-1]= '\0';
}
```

This just puts in a terminating null character, whether `strncpy` was able to do that or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, because your question is a bit confusingly worded, but I *think* you're right, and that your instructor is wrong.

Given the code

```
void simple(char *bar) {
    char MyArray[12];
    strcpy(MyArray, bar);
}
```

if the passed-in `bar` points to a string of 11 or fewer characters, a valid string will be copied to `MyArray`, with no buffer overflow.  But if the string is 12 (or more) characters long, you're right, there'll be a buffer overflow, because `strcpy` will also copy the 13th, terminating null character.

Earlier you asked about `strncpy`. Given the code

```
void simple2(char *bar) {
    char MyArray[12];
    strncpy(MyArray, bar, 12);
}
```

if the passed-in `bar` points to a string of 11 or fewer characters, a valid string will be copied to `MyArray`.  But if the string is 12 characters long, we have a different problem.  `strncpy` will copy 12 characters and stop, meaning that it won't copy the terminating null character.  There won't be a buffer overflow, but `MyArray` still won't end up containing a valid string.

Also, you asked for a credible source.  I wrote the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/)  -- would you consider that credible? :-)

Answer (score 0):

> My instructor says that MyArray can copy at most 12 elements from bar

It will be more correctly to say that the array `MyArray` may accomodate at most 12 elements of the array `bar`. Otherwise there will be an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

So in fact your instructor is right.

The array `MyArray` is declared having only 12 elements

```
char MyArray[12];
```

> but from what I've read, MyArray can only store 11 characters because
>   it needs room for the null character at the end

The terminating zero is also a character. And the function `strcpy` copies all characters from the source string including the terminating zero that is present in the source string.

> So if the received value of bar is 12 or greater, a buffer overflow
>   would occur

What does mean the magic number 12 in this context? is it the number of characters in the array `bar` or it is the length of the string stored in the array bar (that used as an argument is converted to pointer to its first element)?

If the number 12 means the size of the string stored in the array `bar` then the function `strcpy` will try to copy all characters of the array including the terminating zero and in this case the array `MyArray` has to be declared as having 13 elements.

```
char MyArray[13];
```

However if the number 12 means the number of elements in the array `bar` (used as an argument of the function) and it contains a string then the length of the string is evidently is less than 12. So the array MyArray can accept all characters of the source array including the terminating zero.

So the reason for the confusion is that you did not make a common conclusion what the number 12 means whether it is the length of the source string or it is the size of the source array.

In the first case there will be indeed undefined behavior.

In the second case if the source array contains a string then the code will be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` array and *string* are similar, but not the same.

In C,

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.  C11dr §7.1.1 1

---

```
void simple (char *bar) {
    char MyArray[12];
    strcpy(MyArray, bar);
}
```

> My instructor says that `MyArray` can copy at most 12 elements from bar,

This is correct: `MyArray[]` can receive up to 12 characters.

`strcpy()` copies the memory, starting at `bar` to the array `MyArray[]` and continues until it copies a *null character*.  If more that 12  characters (the count of 12 includes the null character) are attempted to be copied, the result is *undefined behavior* ([UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B)).

> `MyArray` can only store 11 characters

Not quite.  `MyArray[]` can store 12 characters.  To treat that data as a *string*, a *null character* must be one of those 12.  When interpreted as a *string*, the string include all the characters up to the null character.  It also include the *null chracter*.  Each element of `MyArray[]` could be an `'x'`, but then that memory would not be a *string* as it lacks a null character.

> So if the received value of `bar` is 12 or greater, a buffer overflow would occur.

Not quite.  If the `strcpy()` attempts to write outside `MyArray[]`, the result is undefined.  Buffer overflow may occur.  The program may stop,  etc.  The result is not defined.  It is *undefined behavior*.

> My instructor says that this will only happen if the received value of `bar` is 13 or greater.

`bar` is a pointer - it likely does not have a "value of 13".  `bar` likely points to memory that is a *string*.  A *string* includes its terminating null character, so the *string* may consists of 12 non-null characters and a final null character for a total of 13 characters.  `MyArray[]` is insufficient to store a copy of that string.

> Who's right?

I suspect the dis-connect is in the imprecise meaning of "`bar` is 13"`.  I see nothing the reported by the instructor as incorrect.